# Azure Datafactory - Credential injection in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-data-factory

How would I inject data source (a.k.a. linked service) credentials for an Azure Datafactory at deployment time? I am coding up some pipelines in VS2015 using the Datafactory plugin and I need to be able to check these files into a git repo without system account credentials exposed in the code. The code needs to be deployed by a help desk person (not me!). Looking for a quick win here, a cursory search has not yielded any success.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, IN VS2015 the feature is configs. On your project right click and choose Add | New Item. Select configuration file.

https://talkingaboutdata.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/config-files-in-azure-data-factory/